# Find the steps without finding the solution with bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods, bisection

We have the equation $x^3+2x-1=0$.How many steps we need to find the solution correct up to $5$ decimal places (without to find the solution correct up to $5$ decimal places with bisection method).

I solved a similar exrcise using the bisection method but i am wondering how i can estimate the steps wihout solving it any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to bound the error after $n$ steps?

Comment: could you explain me this?

Comment: i found that we need $a=0$ and $b=1$ but we do not have the tolerance $ε$

Comment: $10^{-5}$? or am i wrong?

Comment: so with these tips i found that we need $n=17$ please correct me if i am rong

Comment: on other calculator it is shows me $16$ steps..  http://planetcalc.com/3718/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the bisection method , if $x_1 =\frac {a+b} 2$ is the midpoint of the initial interval, and $x_n$ is the midpoint of the interval in the $n^{th}$ step,  the difference between $x_n$ and the  solution $x$ is bounded by

$$ |x_{n}-x|\leq {\frac {|b-a|}{2^{n}}} $$

So, for your case $(a=0,b=1)$, you need to solve ${\frac {1}{2^{n}}}=10^{-5} $ which leads to $n=16.61$ then $n=17$ is the number of steps required.