# Find the solution of this equation correct to $5$ decimal places using Newton's method

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

We have the equation $x^3+2x-1=0$.Find the solution of this equation correct to $5$ decimal places using Newton's method.

Could anyone help me how to use the newton's method when we want to find the solution with correct to five decimal places?

Comment: I think that you received an answer from Felix Marin in your previous post.

Comment: Adding some context, any kind of, would be so easy, and yet...

Answer (score 1):

Try an initial guess: $x_0=1$. Now the derivative of the equation is $3x^2+2$, so the iteration we use is
$$x\leftarrow x-\frac{x^3+2x-1}{3x^2+2}$$
(*x* by itself is on the left, subtracted by *function* over *derivative*.) Iterating this we find
$$x_1=0.6$$
$$x_2=0.464935\dots$$
$$x_3=0.453467\dots$$
$$x_4=0.453397\dots$$
$$x_5=0.453397\dots$$
and so we find the root of the equation to 5 decimal places as **0.45340**.

Answer (score 1):

Make an initial guess. My guess would be $x=0$, so that $f(x) = -1$. Note that $f'(x) = 3x^2+2$.

Now, by the Newton Raphson method, let us start our process:

$x_0=0$

$x_1=0 - \frac{f(0)}{f'(0)} = 0.5$.

$x_2=0.5- \frac{f(0.5)}{f'(0.5)} = 0.5-\frac{1}{22} = \frac{5}{11}=0.45454545$.

$x_2=0.45454545-\frac{f(0.45454545)}{f'(0.454545)} = 0.453398$.

$x_2=0.453398-\frac{f(0.453398)}{f'(0.453398)} = 0.453398$.

Hence my answer is coming to $0.453398$, which when rounded to five decimal places comes to $0.453340$.

Comment: could we take as start point $1$?

Comment: Any point close enough to a root can be taken. You can prove that convergence will occur and it will be of order two in this case. It will be harder to prove (and in fact false in some cases) if you are in an interval where $f'$ vanishes. In this case, $3x^2+2$ is always positive, but say for $3x^2-2$ you would have a problem taking different values.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $x^3+2x=1$ has a unique real solution since the derivative of $f(x)=x^3+2x-1$ is always positive, hence $f(x)$ is an increasing function. Since $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{8}>0$ and $f$ is convex over $\mathbb{R}^+$, Newton's method with starting point $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ converges quadratically to the root of $f$. Newton's iteration in this case is
$$ x \mapsto \frac{1+2x^3}{2+3x^2} $$
so the sequence of approximations is given by
$$ \frac{1}{2},\;\frac{5}{11},\; \frac{1581}{3487},\; \frac{50302634185}{110945952227} $$
and the last two terms yet differ by less than $7\cdot 10^{-7}$. It is not difficult to bound $f'$ on $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and deduce that the last term gives the wanted digits:
$$ \frac{50302634185}{110945952227}=\color{red}{0.45339}76515\ldots $$
If we replace the starting point $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ with the starting point $x_0=\frac{4}{9}$ suggested by the [secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method), we achieve the same accuracy in just $\color{red}{\large 2}$ steps.

By the [(hyperbolic) trigonometric form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root) of the roots of a cubic polynomial, the exact root is given by
$$ \sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}\,\sinh\left(\frac{1}{3}\text{arcsinh}\sqrt{\frac{27}{32}}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Yesterday, I posted this answer in
[another question of $\texttt{@Mantol Inis}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898408/find-the-steps-without-finding-the-solution-with-bisection-method/1898758?noredirect=1#comment3895501_1898758), who is the current OP. However, that question was related to the *Bisection Method* and I had to delete it. $\texttt{@Claude Leibovici}$ calls this question to my attention by remarking that my answer was in the wrong post. Anyway, I just moved it to the right place.

---

> Since $\ds{\verts{x^{3} + 2x - 1}_{\ x\ =\ 0}\,\,\,\,\, =\,\, 1}$ and
>   $\ds{\expo{\ic\theta}}$, with $\ds{\theta \in \mathbb{R}}$, is not a root; there is a root $\ds{z \in \mathbb{C}}$ with $\ds{\verts{z} < 1}$. Anyway, we can check that
>   $$
> \left.\vphantom{\Large A}x^{3} + 2x - 1\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ -1} = -4 < 0
> \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
> \left.\vphantom{\Large A}x^{3} + 2x - 1\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 1} = 2 > 0
> $$
>   You can start with the guess $\ds{x = 0}$. $\texttt{Newton-Rapson}$ finds a real root with $\ds{5}$ decimal places in $\ds{\large\color{#f00}{3\ !!!}}$ steps.

This is a 'short $\texttt{javascript}$ code':

```
/* javascript example */
"use strict";
var maxIter = 4; // Iterations
var       n = 0; // Iteration index
var       x = 0; // Guess
var      x2 = null;

while (n < maxIter) {
      document.write(x + "\n");
      x2 = x*x;
      x -= (x*(x2 + 2.0) - 1.0)/(3.0*x2 + 2.0); // Newton-Rapson
      ++n;
}

document.write(x + "\n");
```

The result is given by:
\begin{align}
&0
\\
&0.5
\\
&0.454545
\\
\imp\quad &\color{#f00}{0.45339}83366790937769
\\
&\color{#f00}{0.45339}76515166477918
\end{align}

and
$\ds{\quad\left.\vphantom{\Large A}x^{3} + 2x - 1\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0.45339}\,\,\,\,\,\, =\,\,\,\,\,\, -2.00217 \times 10^{-5}}$.

> We can modify the code to check the 'tolerance' ( with some definition ) in each iteration. The present example used ( to be brief ) the old 'by inspection method".

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Now, it arrives to the right place. Thanks.